# Multiple Entry Points

Tags: java, android, c++, mobile, entry-point

I have started programming in Android Studio. During this ongoing process, I discovered that Android applications do not use a single entry point (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point) like most regular applications. But according to others, Android applications are not the only type of apps that do this. So my questions are:

How does any application run without a single entry point?

Shouldn't all programs have a single entry point?

Answer (score 1):

Android runs processes and each process is invoked by a main method in java and in turn it runs the native method. All processes communications are managed by Binder mechanism. So technically speaking, Android doesn't have single point entry.

I'm also quite new to Android, correct me if I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html 
document what you're looking for. It might be helpful

...
When the system starts a component, it starts the process for that app (if it's not already running) and instantiates the classes needed for the component. For example, if your app starts the activity in the camera app that captures a photo, that activity runs in the process that belongs to the camera app, not in your app's process. Therefore, unlike apps on most other systems, Android apps don't have a single entry point (there's no main() function, for example).
...